# Apache Spark Graphx - Java Implementation

Tags: apache-spark, spark-graphx, apache-spark-2.0

As per Spark Documentation, it seems GraphX does not have Java API available yet.

IS my assumption correct? If yes then can somebody provide some example where GraphX library is called using Java Code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I read: GraphX java API is on Alpha version:
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html

but In March 2016, Spark team introduces GraphFrames. It support the full set of algorithms available in GraphX, in all 3 language APIs. including Java.

> GraphFrames fully integrate with GraphX via conversions between the
>   two representations, without any data loss.

ref:https://databricks.com/blog/2016/03/03/introducing-graphframes.html